# Angular-UI-Router and IIS publishing

Tags: angularjs, iis, routes, angular-ui-router

I'm attempting to get Angular ui-route to work once deployed on IIS7 but even with URL rewrites setup in the web.config its still not working as perfectly as it does in IIS express.

The 404 state is always intercepted by IIS and displays

> 404 - File or directory not found.
>   The resource you are looking for might have been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable.

But my router handles the 404 redirect fine, and correctly loads the template when using iis express.

Angular config

```
.config(["$stateProvider", "$locationProvider", "growlProvider", "$urlRouterProvider", function ($stateProvider, $locationProvider, growlProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {

    // UI States, URL Routing & Mapping. For more info see: https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router
    // ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    // the known route, with missing '/' - let's create alias
    $urlRouterProvider.when("", "/");

    $stateProvider
        .state("home", {
            url: "/",
            templateUrl: urlbase + "/views/login",
            controller: "LoginCtrl"
        })
        .state("modal", {
            url: "/modal",
            templateUrl: urlbase + "/views/modal",
            controller: "ModalCtrl"
        })
        .state("about", {
            url: "/about",
            templateUrl: urlbase + "/views/about",
            controller: "AboutCtrl"
        })
        .state("index", {
            url: "/index",
            templateUrl: urlbase + "/views/index",
            controller: "IndexCtrl"
        })
        .state("login", {
            url: "/login",
            //layout: "basic",
            templateUrl: urlbase + "/views/login",
            controller: "LoginCtrl"
        })
        .state("404", {
            url: "{path:.*}",
            templateUrl: urlbase + "/views/404",
            controller: "Error404Ctrl"
        });

    $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);

    growlProvider.globalTimeToLive(3000);

}])
```

web.config for url rewriting

```
<system.webServer>
  <rewrite>
    <rules>
      <rule name="Main Rule" stopProcessing="true">
        <match url=".*" />
        <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
          <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
          <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
        </conditions>
        <action type="Rewrite" url="/" />
      </rule>
    </rules>
  </rewrite>
  <staticContent>
    <clear />
    <mimeMap fileExtension=".xml" mimeType="text/x-cross-domain-policy" />
  </staticContent>
</system.webServer>
```

Am I missing something here? Thanks!

Comment: The error says that you are trying to acces at one ressource but he doesn't find it. Are you sure that all your template is available?

Comment: Yes 100% sure, i can access all the templates when I hard code the relative path in a browser. And the routing works perfectly in iis express, so it must be something to do with IIS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case anyone comes across a similar problem, I solved this on the hosted server by adding a custom error page URL specifically for the 404 status code, using the "execute a URL on this site" option.

Comment: I'm having the same issue on iis8. What did you put in the URL (relative to site root) field? Just your angular site's main page?

Comment: I have a custom 404 page which I declared in my angular module, so I just use the relative uri to navigate to that state from the root. So mine is just /404.cshtml otherwise if that doesnt work for you and you can navigate with the full url to the page you want I'm sure using a redirect to the absolute path would work just the same way.

Answer (score 0):

This situation will happen when you turn on the html5Mode ($locationProvider.html5Mode(true).

> Setting html5mode to true in an AngularJS application it removes the
>   hash (#) prefix from the angular virtual urls, a side effect of this
>   is that if you try to navigate directly to a deep link in your angular
>   app or refresh an internal page you may get a 404 page not found
>   error.

Here is what I did to resolve this issue. In my **web.config**, I just added the following code snipped. It works for both IIS server and when running the application on Visual Studio debugging mode.

```
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
        <rewrite>
          <rules>
            <rule name="AngularJS" stopProcessing="true">
              <match url=".*" />
              <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
                <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
                <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
              </conditions>
              <action type="Rewrite" url="/" />
            </rule>
          </rules>
        </rewrite>

      </system.webServer>
......other configurations ...
</configuration>
```